# Unable to join and get the data from database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, join

I want to join three table and get the data from the function but unable to do so. I am able to get the category joint data but not the product line data.

I have three tables. One is `cv_products` second one is `cv_category` and last one is `product_line` . I have a table field in `cv_products` named `product_line`.

This is my function in the model

```
public function get_products($id = 0, $slug = FALSE){
if($id === 0 && $slug === FALSE){

$this->db->order_by('cv_products.id', 'DESC');

$this->db->select('cv_products.*, cv_category.name as categoryname', 'product_line.name as linename','cv_category.id as category_id' );

$this->db->join('cv_category','cv_category.id = cv_products.category', 'left');

$this->db->join('product_line','product_line.id = cv_products.product_line', 'left');

$query= $this->db->get('cv_products');

return $query->result_array();

}
$this->db->select('cv_products.*, cv_category.name as categoryname', 'product_line.name as linename','cv_category.id as category_id' );

$this->db->join('cv_category','cv_category.id = cv_products.category', 'left');

$this->db->join('product_line','product_line.id = cv_products.product_line', 'left');

$query= $this->db->get_where('cv_products', array('cv_products.id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug));

return $query->row_array();



}
```

In view it giving an error like 
`Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: linename`.

as I have a field `name` in both `cv_products`, `cv_category` and `product_line` so at the time of selection i've given `product_line.name as linename`. It's alright with the `cv_category` joint but unable to get the same in case of `product_line` joint time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes seem to be a little off in your select call.

Change this:

```
$this->db->select('cv_products.*, cv_category.name as categoryname', 'product_line.name as linename','cv_category.id as category_id' );
```

To this:

```
$this->db->select('cv_products.*, cv_category.name as categoryname, product_line.name as linename,cv_category.id as category_id' );
```

Notice that I open the quotation at the start of the select statement and close it at the end. individual fields to not need to be quoted as `$this->db->select()` then potentially treats them as function parameters.

Repeat this approach for the second select statement in your function also.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for that,, I took almost 5hrs to understand this,,Thanks friend